# Closing a Jquery list menu when clicked outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu, onclick

I have found a great jquery plugin at Codrops, for styling a drop down list. The plugin works and looks great. I was able to implement it without any major issues.

I only have one problem, I can't find a way to close the menu when I click outside the menu. In other words, I want the menu options to close when I anywhere else in the page (not only when I click on the menu itself). I found similar subjects here, but I was not able to apply it to my needs. I would really appreciate any help I can get.

The link to the plugin: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/

Comment: One thing that you can try is adding your own custom event to the _initEvents method that fires on the window. You could utilize the close method within the plugin and add whatever check are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
$(document).mousedown(function(){
if($('.cd-dropdown.cd-active').length){ $('.cd-dropdown span').trigger('click');
}else{} });
```

Comment: @stahish Your piece of code worked very well. I lot of people that downloaded this plugin were looking for this solution. I will direct them here.

Comment: @stahish - The main reason I wanted this feature was because I will use more than one drop down list on the same page. What would you add to the code above so that when I click on other menus, the previously open one closes up?